# SQL Print the name of all Employees together with the name of their supervisor

Tags: mysql, sql, sql-server

I'm trying to learn SQL and have this question: print the name of all employees together with the name of their supervisor.

Here is my `Employees` table:

[Table Employee](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BOSMi.jpg)

How do I use a `SELECT` command in new query to get the result out? I tried with a self join.

Ty

Max (SQL NOOB)

Comment: where is your attempt?

Comment: `self join` is the answer. What you try and why didnt work out?

Comment: Please see [Why should I provide an MCVE for what seems to me to be a very simple SQL query](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-an-mcve-for-what-seems-to-me-to-be-a-very-simple-sql-query)

Comment: MySQL and SQL Server use different sql dialects. Focus on the one you actually use; don't add tags for those that are not directly related to your environment.

Answer (score -2, accepted):

An inner join should do it. Here's the syntax, but you'll have to apply it to your database:

```
SELECT c.name, o.name
FROM cats c
INNER JOIN owners o
ON c.owner_id = o.id
```

"cats c" basically means "Cats table, which I'm nicknaming c." "owners o" basically means "Owners table, which I'm nicknaming o." In your select, you tell it which fields you want by their name, and which table their in: [table nickname].[fieldname]. The ON is where you specify a common field from each table, which tells it how to join the two tables together. In the case of this example, we're saying that we want the owner who's id is equal to the owner id field of the cats table. The owner_id field is a foreign key of the owners table.

I know answers like this are frustrating when you're learning, but the truth is you'll learn better if you have to figure a bit out for yourself, and I can't do your homework for you (I mean that nicely..)

Comment: I know you mean well, but still is a big step going from INNER JOIN  to SELF JOIN.

Answer (score -1):

Try the below

```
SELECT  t1.EmployeeName AS Manager, t2.EmployeeID as EmployeeName
FROM  Employee t1 
LEFT  JOIN Employee t2 ON  t1.ManagerID=t2.EmployeeID
```